# How to convert first letter to uppercase in c++?

Tags: c++, string

I have a Structure

```
struct StudentRecord{
char StudentFamilyName[20]
}gRecs[50];

cout << "Family Name: ";
cin >> gRecs[50].StudentFamilyName;
char str[20];
str[20] = toupper(gRecs[i].StudentFamilyName[0]);
cout << str;
```

What i want to do is to  store the first letter of family name as
upper case and the rest as lower case? How do I do that?
I used `toupper` but when I implement it doesnot work. Could anyone help me out? Thank you.

**Note: This was an exam question.**

Comment: Show how you used `toupper()` so we can tell you what you did wrong.

Comment: "It doesn't work" is not a useful problem description.

Comment: my bad sorry :( i ve edited it

Comment: So you've set character 20 of `str` (which by the way is out of bounds, so UB). What about the other characters?

Answer (score 2):

Here's how to capitalize a string using character arithmetic:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


string ToCapitalize(string input)
{
    if (input.length() > 1 && input[0] >= 'a' && input[0] <= 'z')
    {
        input[0] -= 32;
    }
    return input;
}

int main() {

    std::string StudentFamilyName("smith");
    cout << StudentFamilyName << std::endl;
    cout << "Capitalized: " << ToCapitalize(StudentFamilyName) << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem isn't with `toupper`.  There are a couple of them, actually.

```
cin >> gRecs[50]
```

`gRecs` is size 50, so index 50 is out of bounds.  To insert into the first record you would use

```
cin >> gRecs[0].StudentFamilyName;
```

Second record: `gRecs[1]`, etc.

Next,

```
char str[20];
str[20] = toupper(str[0]);
```

You declare `str` in which nothing is populated, and then call `toupper` on it.
And the index (`[20]`) is the 21st character (which is out of bounds).  You are attempting to convert the 21st character in the `str` `toupper`.

What you need is something like:

```
// i is the index into your student records array, possibly in a loop
cin >> gRecs[i].StudentFamilyName;
gRecs[i].StudentFamilyName[0] = toupper(gRecs[i].StudentFamilyName[0]);
```